# Can't access web server via hostname

Tags: web-server

I had setup my hostname to raspi a few days ago, and I could access my web server fine via `raspi.local`, but it's suddenly stopped working, and I get 'This page is not available'.

A few things to note:

- I can access it via the IP address of the Pi
- `/etc/hostname` has my desired hostname in it
- I have Avahi installed on my Pi
- I have Bonjour installed on my Windows computer
- `hostname` gives me my correct hostname

Could anyone please help me? It just suddenly stopped working - the only thing I've done from the time it was working and isn't is turn it off via `sudo halt`. I can't find any help on the internet, they all say to do the above!

Comment: Do you happen to have a monitor attached to see if anything got logged to the console?  Have you tried to restart the Pi and check what's logged in /var/log/syslog?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Not connected to a monitor, but if necessary, It is possible. Doesn't look like there's an error in the log!

Comment: Is the Pi still running but having network issues our is the Pi completely down and needs a reboot to become responsive again?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn I connected a monitor to the pi and used Midori to browse to a website - it works. So the network itself seems to work, it's just the hostname that doesn't. A reboot does not fix the problem. I can use ssh, FTP, and access my web server via the IP address but not the host name

Comment: This question is about name resolution. So please tell us about your name server.

Comment: @MaxRied Sorry - I don't really know anything about networking - what's my nameserver? How do I find it?

Comment: If you set a hostname on a computer, the name does NOT get populated to other devices. Your computer doesn't know anything about your rpi. Thing is, technically avahi is exactly what you are looking for. You might want to have a look at DNS, but this is really beyond the scope of this question here. Maybe your router offers a configuration option for setting domain names for local devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the IP address works but not the hostname, it looks like you are having trouble resolving the name of your Raspberry Pi. This may be the result of a stale cache after changing your hostname, but assuming you have a static IP address configured for your Raspberry Pi, you can add an entry to the [hosts file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) on your PC to solve the problem. The entry is made up of an IP address and a hostname so in your case:

```
0.0.0.0    raspi
```

replace the 0's in the line above with the IP address of your Raspberry Pi.

Full details of where the hosts file is located and how to edit it can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/).

You can verify the resolution of a host to IP address by entering the following command at the Windows command line.

```
nslookup raspi
```